# How can we find factorials in decimal form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I've heard of factorials such as $5!$ and $3!$, which work like this: $5!=5\times4\times3\times2\times1=120$ and $3!=3\times2\times1=6$.  At least this is what we get.  Also, surprisingly, $0!=1$, but how can we figure out values for factorials in decimal form such as $(2.5)!$ and $(3.34)!$?  Maybe we should use gamma for part of it?  What else?  I also know that we can draw graphs for factorials.  I just want to know how to find values for factorials in decimal form?

Comment: Use $n!=\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} dx$.

Comment: Seems too complicated...

Comment: @VladInTheTaylor that is a very special function known as the Gamma function. If you want to calculate things like $(2.5)!$ that is the only way you are going to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). For exapmle, it explains $(\frac{1}{2})!=\sqrt{\pi}$. If you are interested in an answer, you should not immediately say that it is too complicated.

Comment: How have I seen that kind of math before?

Comment: @VladInTheTaylor You'll see it as soon as you take calculus, and the gamma function really is one of the best generalizations of factorial to non-integers, for a variety of reasons that are probably too technical to explain if you think the gamma function is already too complicated.

Comment: Remember to put answers in the answers instead of the comments.

Comment: [See my answer to an earlier question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/971213/166353) It doesn't require knowledge of integrals.

Comment: Hmm...eight up-votes and not helping me.

Comment: Sorry about that...

Comment: @VladInTheTaylor I just want to mention: if you haven't learned limits yet, then you probably won't be able to understand any of the answers here.

Comment: It's bizarre to suggest "maybe we should use $\Gamma$ for part of it" in your question but then dismiss @user2345215's comment, which is just $\Gamma$ translated appropriately to answer your question, as "too complicated".

Comment: Gamma function (shifted by 1) is the definitive answer here. It straight-forwardly generalizes the factorial property and is used everywhere you need a factorial of a real number. I'm sorry you can't yet understand the beautiful details of its definition, but it should suffice to you that there *is* this function and it *does* what you want, and there is software that calculates it for you. But don't expect that a smooth curve that goes through $n!$ is something that you could calculate with primary school math. Even simpler transcendential functions such as $e^x$ aren't as easy as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many functions $F\colon[0,\infty)$ such that $f(n)=n!$ for $n=0,1,2\dots$. How to choose the right one? It seems reasonable to require that $F$ be continuous, but this is not enough. An important property of the factorial is 
$$
(n+1)!=(n+1)\,n!.
$$
We then add the requirement
$$
F(x+1)=(x+1)\,F(x),\quad x>0.
$$
There are still many functions satisfying all these requirements. The Gamma function, defined as
$$
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty x^n\,e^{-x}\,dx,
$$
**Note**: this is not the $\Gamma$ function, which is defined as $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}\,e^{-x}\,dx$, so that $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

is the unique that satisfies the additional requirement that $\ln F(x)$ is a convex function. To summarize, $\Gamma$ is the only function such that

1. $F(0)=1$ and $F(x+1)=(x+1)\,F(x)$ if $x>0$.
2. $\ln F(x)$ is convex.

It turns out that $\Gamma(z)$ can be extended to complex numbers $z$ which are not a negative integer.

Comment: Note that this is (sadly) not the Gamma function as is usually defined. It's shifted one unit way away from the natural definition which also agrees with the factorial and simplifies many formulas. Wikipedia says it's called the $\Pi$ function.

Comment: I just copied from one of the comments to the OP question, and did not realize that the integral was $\Gamma(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know how to find values for factorials in decimal form?

Hi;

According to Meck in Numerical Analysis you can use this truncated series

$$f(x)=\log(x!)$$

$$\log(x!)\approx\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (x)-x+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi \
)+\frac{1}{12x}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{x^2}\left ( \frac{1}{30}-\frac{1}{x^2}\left ( \frac{1}{105}-\frac{1}{x^2}\left ( \frac{1}{140}-\frac{1}{x^2}\left ( \frac{1}{99} \right ) \right ) \right ) \right ) \right )$$

because the above series yields about 8 digits if $x\geq5.5$ we use the relation $$\text{B) }3.34!=\frac{5.34!}{5.34\cdot4.34}$$

Now we just plugin to f:

$$ f (5.34) = 5.37784377585049$$

$$5.34!\approx e^{5.37784377585049}\approx 216.554830892397$$

Now into B:

$$3.34!\approx\frac{216.554830892397}{5.34\cdot 4.34}\approx9.34408735447613$$

which is off by one in the 10th decimal place.

Comment: Note that the leading three terms of the given approximation for $\log (x!)$ are together just the logarithm of *Stirling's approximation*: $x! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question that could be easily answered, as there are many ways (infinite ways of drawing a curve through the integer factorials) of defining the factorial function over the real numbers.

One of the most used functions that extends the factorial to the reals, and the one that you yourself suggested is the gamma function, for which the equality
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$
for integer $n$ exists.
The problem is that the gamma function cannot be expresed without using the language of calculus, which I assume you have yet to learn.

Currently it would be impossible for you to calculate the values of non-integer factorials.

Comment: What happens if you use this gamma thing using a whole number for $n$?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute...

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

$0!=1$ because that makes the functional equation $n!=(n-1)!*n$ hold (and because it is generally smart to define the empty product to be $1$.

To make any sense of things like $(\frac12)!$, we need to find some way to define factorial of non-integers, and the common way to do that is to observe that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for integers and turn that into the definition of factorials for non-integers.

There are other functions that satisfy the functional equation, and agree with $n!$ on the integers, but $\Gamma$ is the most useful.

Comment: @Travis: Of course, answer edited.