# Fraction Factorial

Tags: factorial

How do we find factorial of fractions?
For eg: $\frac{1!}{2!}=(\frac{\pi}{4})^{\frac{1}{2}}$
Factorials are used in combinatorics and they can only be functioned on integers to give integers.Then how do we get this?

Comment: This question has been asked many, _many_ times on this site before.

Comment: the factorial function has an extension from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ by Tietze.  There is a unique such function which is logarithmically convex. Think about it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396889/how-to-find-the-factorial-of-a-fraction?rq=1

Comment: I particularly like [my answer to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/971213/166353), but I think I'm biased.

Answer (score 3):

Related to factorials is the gamma $(\Gamma)$ function. For positve integers it satisfies: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. For non-integers it is given by: $\Gamma(t)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$.

Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: I think you mean $\Gamma(t)$. Also, that identity works only for positive integers.