# Gamma function of $4/3$

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

I know how to calculate the value of $\big(\frac12\big)!$ using the gamma function, but I don't know how to find the value of $\big(\frac13\big)!$ or $\big(\frac16\big)!$ using the gamma function. I got an answer with this formula $\Gamma(n+1/p)=\frac{\Gamma(1/p)(pn−p+1)!^p}{p^n}$, to calculate it but I still don't understand it. How can I use it to get the value in this case of gamma function of $\frac43$. Can any one put all the steps to follow?

Comment: Related: [how to find the factorial of a fraction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396889/how-to-find-the-factorial-of-a-fraction).

Comment: If what you desire are closed forms, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#General_rational_arguments) mentions the existence of such are known, though they are in terms complete elliptic integrals of the first kind. A number of such results are collected in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf), and the specific value $\Gamma(4/3)=\Gamma(1/3)/3$ is given on the same Wikipedia above. The proofs for these are by no means easy however.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are very few values for which $$\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad 0 \leq p$$ has a known value.

However, we can develop quite good approximations in the same spirit as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810559/approximation-of-big-gamma1x-big-1-for-0-leq-x-leq-1-for-the-art) of mine.

Let $x=\frac{1}{p}$ and write
$$\Gamma \left(1+x\right)\sim 1+x(1-x) \sum_{k=0}^6 d_k\, x^k$$ and the $d_k$'s would be computed in order to  match the function, first and second derivative values at $x=0$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$. This leads to
$$d_0=-\gamma \qquad d_1=-\gamma +\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$
$$d_2=-246+38 \gamma -\frac{9 \gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{3 \pi ^2}{4}+2 \pi ^{5/2}+4 \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(24+\log ^2(4)+\gamma  (\gamma +\log (16))\right)$$
$$d_3=1211-125 \gamma +16 \gamma ^2+\frac{8 \pi ^2}{3}-12 \pi ^{5/2}-8 \sqrt{\pi }
   (68+(-2+\gamma +\log (4)) (2+3 \gamma +\log (64)))$$
$$d_4=-2386+2 (79-14 \gamma ) \gamma -\frac{14 \pi ^2}{3}+26 \pi ^{5/2}+4 \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(268+\psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \left(13 \psi
  \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-20\right)\right)$$
$$d_5=4 \left(529+\gamma  (6 \gamma -19)+\pi ^2-6 \pi ^{5/2}-4 \sqrt{\pi } \left(60+\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \left(3 \psi
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-2\right)\right)\right)$$
$$d_6=-696-8 (\gamma -1) \gamma -\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}+8 \pi ^{5/2}+16 \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(20+\psi\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\right)$$
Making them rational to high accuracy, the $d_k$'s are
$$\left\{-\frac{33841}{58628},\frac{19541}{47448},-\frac{12261}{24970},\frac{30367}{6
   8303},-\frac{45695}{134763},\frac{21117}{128032},-\frac{6099}{165595}\right\}$$ and the maximum error is less that $3 \times 10^{-6}$.

Listing for a few values of $p$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.00000000 & 1.00000000 \\
 2 & 0.88622693 & 0.88622693 \\
 3 & 0.89298092 & 0.89297951 \\
 4 & 0.90640551 & 0.90640248 \\
 5 & 0.91817214 & 0.91816874 \\
 6 & 0.92772247 & 0.92771933 \\
 7 & 0.93544026 & 0.93543756 \\
 8 & 0.94174496 & 0.94174270 \\
 9 & 0.94696723 & 0.94696535 \\
 10 & 0.95135233 & 0.95135077 \\
 11 & 0.95508084 & 0.95507953 \\
 12 & 0.95828678 & 0.95828568 \\
 13 & 0.96107099 & 0.96107006 \\
 14 & 0.96351044 & 0.96350965 \\
 15 & 0.96566474 & 0.96566406 \\
 16 & 0.96758065 & 0.96758007 \\
 17 & 0.96929538 & 0.96929487 \\
 18 & 0.97083880 & 0.97083836 \\
 19 & 0.97223524 & 0.97223485 \\
 20 & 0.97350461 & 0.97350427
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Why gamma of 1+x is similar to the other function, can you write the demostración. And the letter gamma and psi are nunbers, functions etc?

Comment: @SergioGarcia Those letters are very common in special function theory. $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi$ is the digamma function.

Comment: What inspires that choice of not-quite Taylor series with $x(1-x)$ factored out the front? I don’t follow. I recognise the first two $d_k$ as derivatives of $\Gamma$ however (although the knowledge of $d_{3,4,5,6}$ is impressive and mysterious)

Comment: @FShrike. The plot of these functions make me thinking about the excess Gibbs energy function for a binary system. So, basically, I use the Redlich-Kister expansion. That is all. Cheers.